# Multiple Tabs within Visual Studio

Tags: python-3.x

I am brand new to programming, and I think I have a simple question for those of you that have been programming for quite some time.
How do I add multiple python scripts (as multiple tabs) within Visual Studio?
I keep going to File, New Project and that gives me one tab to work from.
I would like to have multiple tabs so I can go back and forth looking at the files I have created.
Thank you in advance.
-Robert

Answer (score 0):

So, I had to do more research and here is the answer:
In the right pane of Visual Studio there is a few lines of references to Python.
To keep your original project, and add a new tab:
1.Right click on your project in the right pane.
2.Click add new item.
3.In the new window click empty Python file.
4.Rename that tab (at the bottom of the window).
You are golden!